# FFmpeg vs OpenSL-ES

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on an music player for android,i want to know which would be better for me?
FFMpeg or OpenSL-ES ?  which one is easy to deal with?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(old question but since i'm passing by...)

You can't compare both, they don't do the same job :

- FFMpeg will decode your stream (example : MP3 file) to output PCM for instance
- OpenSL will transmit PCM samples to your audio hardware to output the sound (and apply filters and effects)

Actually, OpenSL with API 14 (Android 4.0) is also able to decode some audio codecs such as MP3.